# Django autoincrement field

Tags: django, postgresql

I was trying to make an auto-increment for a certain field and don't know the proper way to do it. I am using postgres for administrating my database: I tried the Autofield data type but it didn't work. I guess django is using a default id field and I would like to replace that with my WO_ID field.

```
models.py

class Workorder(models.Model): 
    WO_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
    WO_DateDefWO = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    WO_DateSched = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_DateFinished = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_ST_ID_Sign = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Status_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    WO_Type_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    WO_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Kons_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_CustAdr = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Debt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_PropCode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_DepCode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_PhoneNo = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_ReasonCompl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_NightShift = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    WO_Priority = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_RE_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_MapUrl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.WO_ID
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django import forms
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from MMS.models import Workorder
from MMS import forms
from MMS.forms import CreateWorkorder
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from . import forms


def workorders_list(request):
    workorders_all = Workorder.objects.all().values_list('WO_ID', flat=True)
    return render(request, "workorders_list.html")

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html")

def workorder_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CreateWorkorder_item = form.save(commit=False)
            CreateWorkorder_item.save()
            return redirect('/workorder/' + str(CreateWorkorder_item.WO_ID) + '/')
    else:
        form = CreateWorkorder()
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_create.html', {'form': form})


def workorder_edit(request, id=None):
    item = get_object_or_404(Workorder, WO_ID=id)
    form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST or None, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/workorder/' + str(item.WO_ID) + '/')
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_edit.html', {'form': form})


def workorder(request, id):
    workorder = Workorder.objects.get(WO_ID=id)
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder.html', {'workorder': workorder})
```

postgresql autoincrement code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.MMS_workorder_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
alter table MMS_workorder ALTER COLUMN "WO_ID" SET DEFAULT nextval('MMS_workorder_id_seq');
```

Comment: I'm really sorry if it came across as too rude. As I pointed out, please read the PEP8 style guide. The property names should be written in `snake_case` - all small letters, word divided by underscore (`_`). No capitalization of words in snake_case. Don't add prefix to the model class properties - `WO_NightShift` should be just `nightshift` or `night_shift`. You have already encapsulation in the class, there is no need to repeat the namespacing in the property names, it is considered very bad practice.

Comment: Do you use `python2` or `python3`? For a new project it is highly recommended to use `python2` and also Django 2. In that case you shouldn't define `__unicode__` method on your model class, but the method `__str__` instead.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Django gives each model the autoincrement field called `id`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

If you want to create an extra auto increment field, you can use `AutoField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField

**Create custom id field**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    wo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This skips creation of default `id` field and creates autoincrement primary field with name `wo_id`.

Comment: I tried the Autofield but whenever I added a new record it didn't autoincrement

Comment: Do you want to rename default id field to wo_id or have two fields - id and wo_id. Because Django allows only one AutoField per model...

Comment: I want to skip the default id and use the wo_id field

Comment: @GentBytyqi share code you've tried, check actual db model (on dbms side), unapplied migrations.

Comment: I just tried the autofield data type but it didn't work, basically I have an html template, I will edit the code and include the views.py

Comment: @GentBytyqi see updated answer. You can create custom autoincrement field.

Comment: `it didn't work` show error message, describe what and how _"does not work"_. `basically I have an html template` no idea how is this related to your original question. Please describe your actual problem. @GentBytyqi

Comment: @Ivan Starostin I solved this issue, I hade to remove the id from the form so that when i save the form it doesn't require to add the id